# Asterisk hacking defence: "Call setup" in tcpdump from denied IP number

Tags: security, linux-networking, asterisk

I am running Asterisk 11.7 on Ubuntu for my small business. These last days someone could access the server and make all phone extensions ring in regular intervals. I would like to understand how that person can access my server in order to fix the security hole. But IT is not my major, rather a hobby and I clearly reached my limits now :-(

My security measures are: Fail2Ban (several hits per day with 6 hour bans), networks restricted with deny/permit (access from a un-defined networks results in Fail2Ban to kick in), good passwords, different user names and extensions, 'allowguest=no'.

Despite that, when I monitor the tcpdump of the server network device with Wireshark, using the function Telephony -> VoIP calls, I can see 'CALL SETUP' from IP numbers, which I have not allowed and which are denied. I have confirmed that the deny/permit rules work. How is that possible?

Below is an example of the UDP stream content, when I filter for one of the "violating" IP numbers (50.30.37.184):

---

```
INVITE sip:00972597740379@185.50.232.119 SIP/2.0
To: 00972597740379<sip:00972597740379@185.50.232.119>
From: 3001<sip:3001@185.50.232.119>;tag=b7544775
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 50.30.37.184:5071;branch=z9hG4bK-c77dfca41a3022494888aee924ac6fc2;rport
Call-ID: c77dfca41a3022494888aee924ac6fc2
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Contact: <sip:3001@50.30.37.184:5071>
Max-Forwards: 70
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE
User-Agent: sipcli/v1.8
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 281

v=0
o=sipcli-Session 1974783073 2136912366 IN IP4 50.30.37.184
s=sipcli
c=IN IP4 50.30.37.184
t=0 0
m=audio 5073 RTP/AVP 18 0 8 101
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
INVITE sip:900972597740379@185.50.232.119 SIP/2.0
To: 900972597740379<sip:900972597740379@185.50.232.119>
From: 3001<sip:3001@185.50.232.119>;tag=f28b82cf
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 50.30.37.184:5071;branch=z9hG4bK-41939a537a9d2f3071772b2f91b215b7;rport
Call-ID: 41939a537a9d2f3071772b2f91b215b7
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Contact: <sip:3001@50.30.37.184:5071>
Max-Forwards: 70
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE
User-Agent: sipcli/v1.8
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 277

v=0
o=sipcli-Session 71968886 85419647 IN IP4 50.30.37.184
s=sipcli
c=IN IP4 50.30.37.184
t=0 0
m=audio 5073 RTP/AVP 18 0 8 101
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
```

---

Can anyone give me some hints and suggestions how I can tighten up my server security to disallow this unwanted access?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Is the server local or remote? Is it behind firewall?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are using a GUI with Asterisk (eg: Elastix or FreePBX) - as this will build your dialplan (and may be creating a weakness).  FreePBX had some pretty major security holes allowing attackers to modify the dialplan.  Is your code up to date?  (Even if it is, exposing the configuration GUI to the internet is a major flaw in the FreePBX design - so disable it anyways).  With every hole they fix someone eventually finds a new one.

Next - a simple quesiton: have you disabled SIP allowguest?

Next - Fail2Ban is fairly dumb, in other words, only if Asterisk says that a registration/dial attempt was refused will fail2ban actually do anything.  So don't consider it a security system.  In fact Digium warns NOT to use fail2ban as a security system (see http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?p=159984),

I would suggest you read this page http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+security on how to secure your PBX.  You need to consider security from the perspective of perimeter, PBX configuration, and PBX-integrated monitoring.

If you post more details of your environment you might get some more suggestions.  The packet dump above doesn't give much of value except the geographic origin of the caller (Graz, Austria) and the agent (sipcli).  Tools like [SecAst](https://telium.io/en/security-for-asterisk/) can block based on geographic IP and SIP agent but you should still address the underlying dialplan issue.